# Is there a way to optimize pandas apply function during groupby?

Tags: python, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe - df as below :

```
Stud_id card    Nation  Gender  Age  Code   Amount  yearmonth
111     1       India   M      Adult 543    100     201601
111     1       India   M      Adult 543    100     201601
111     1       India   M      Adult 543    150     201602
111     1       India   M      Adult 612    100     201602
111     1       India   M      Adult 715    200     201603
222     2       India   M      Adult 715    200     201601
222     2       India   M      Adult 543    100     201604
222     2       India   M      Adult 543    100     201603
333     3       India   M      Adult 543    100     201601
333     3       India   M      Adult 543    100     201601
333     4       India   M      Adult 543    150     201602
333     4       India   M      Adult 612    100     201607
```

Now, I want two dataframes as below :

df_1 :

```
card    Code    Total_Amount    Avg_Amount
1       543     350             175
2       543     200             100
3       543     200             200
4       543     150             150
1       612     100             100
4       612     100             100
1       715     200             200
2       715     200             200
```

Logic for df_1 :

```
1.  Total_Amount : For each unique card and unique Code get the sum of amount ( For eg : card : 1 , Code : 543 = 350 )
2.  Avg_Amount: Divide the Total amount by no.of unique yearmonth for each unique card and unique Code ( For eg : Total_Amount = 350, No. Of unique yearmonth is 2 = 175
```

df_2 :

```
Code    Avg_Amount
543     156.25
612     100
715     200
```

Logic for df_2 :

```
1.  Avg_Amount: Sum of Avg_Amount of each Code in df_1 (For eg. Code:543 the Sum of Avg_Amount is 175+100+200+150 = 625. Divide it by no.of rows - 4. So 625/4 = 156.25
```

Code to create the data frame - df :

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'Cus_id': (111,111,111,111,111,222,222,222,333,333,333,333), 
                     'Card': (1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,4,4), 
                     'Nation':('India','India','India','India','India','India','India','India','India','India','India','India'), 
                     'Gender': ('M','M','M','M','M','M','M','M','M','M','M','M'),
                     'Age':('Adult','Adult','Adult','Adult','Adult','Adult','Adult','Adult','Adult','Adult','Adult','Adult'),
                     'Code':(543,543,543,612,715,715,543,543,543,543,543,612),
                     'Amount': (100,100,150,100,200,200,100,100,100,100,150,100),
                     'yearmonth':(201601,201601,201602,201602,201603,201601,201604,201603,201601,201601,201602,201607)})
```

Code to get the required df_2 :

```
 df1 = df_toy.groupby(['Card','Code'])['yearmonth','Amount'].apply(
                         lambda x: [sum(x.Amount),sum(x.Amount)/len(set(x.yearmonth))]).apply(
                         pd.Series).reset_index()
    df1.columns= ['Card','Code','Total_Amount','Avg_Amount']
    df2 = df1.groupby('Code')['Avg_Amount'].apply(lambda x: sum(x)/len(x)).reset_index(
                              name='Avg_Amount')
```

Though the code works fine, since my dataset is huge its taking time. I am looking for the optimized code ? I think apply function is taking time ? Is there a better optimized code pls ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For DataFrame 1 you can do this:

```
tmp = df.groupby(['Card', 'Code'], as_index=False) \
        .agg({'Amount': 'sum', 'yearmonth': pd.Series.nunique})

df1 = tmp.assign(Avg_Amount=tmp.Amount / tmp.yearmonth) \
         .drop(columns=['yearmonth'])

   Card  Code  Amount  Avg_Amount
0     1   543     350       175.0
1     1   612     100       100.0
2     1   715     200       200.0
3     2   543     200       100.0
4     2   715     200       200.0
5     3   543     200       200.0
6     4   543     150       150.0
7     4   612     100       100.0
```

For DataFrame 2 you can do this:

```
df1.groupby('Code', as_index=False) \
   .agg({'Avg_Amount': 'mean'})

   Code  Avg_Amount
0   543      156.25
1   612      100.00
2   715      200.00
```